# How do you create a 'remote' branch locally: within ~/Library?

Tags: git

I want to create a 'remote' branch at:

```
$~/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository
```

...from which I can push/pull from another local 'work directory'.

I believe I should use the following:

> git remote add ...

But I need to generate a *.git target file.  I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

**Revision**

[image]

1) First I go to the destination ('remote') directory to create a .git repository:

```
$~/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository:git init
```

> Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/Ric/Library/Application
>   Support/GIT Repository/.git

2) Return to source (workarea).  In this example, using 'burp' project:

```
$~/workarea/burp:ls
burp/       burp.xcodeproj/
$~/workarea/burp:
```

3) Attempt to create a remote directory:

```
$~/workarea/burp:git add myRemoteBurp ~/Library/Application\ Support/GIT\ Repository/.git
```

Got a fatal error:

> fatal: /Users/Ric/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository/.git:
>   '/Users/Ric/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository/.git' is
>   outside repository

Checking for remote-repository infrastructure:

```
$~/workarea/burp:ls "/Users/Ric/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository/.git"
HEAD        branches/   config      description hooks/      info/       objects/    refs/
```

...I'm lost here.

Answer (score 0):

from the other "work directory" you can do:

```
git remote add lib_repo ~/Library/Application\ Support/GIT\ Repository/.git
```

and then you will be able to:

```
git push lib_repo master
```

or

```
git pull lib_repo master
```

obviously it works as well the other way around.

---

Ok, you say you're not confused about `git remote add` and `git add`, but you actually are, or you wouldn't have any issues.

Your error:

> fatal: /Users/Ric/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository/.git: '/Users/Ric/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository/.git' is outside repository

is only caused because when you're doing:

```
git add myRemoteBurp ~/Library/Application\ Support/GIT\ Repository/.git
```

what you're asking git to do is to add the **files** `myRemoteBurp` and `~/Library/Application\ Support/GIT\ Repository/.git` **within** the current repository's index. This is the step to do before doing a commit in your normal git flow:

```
echo "Hello World" > README.md
git add README.md
git ci -m "added README file placeholder"
git push origin master
```

And thus, the error git is giving you is perfectly legitimate, as git cannot add files from outside the workspace's path within the repository's index.

What I told you to do is something different, it's about remotes. A remote is just **another repository** your current repository can push to/pull from.
A remote **can be** hosted at github, bitbucket or gitlab, but it can also be hosted on a server you can SSH to, or within another directory on your computer. And that last case seems to be what you were asking for.

So let's start over and follow my directions:

```
% cd "/Users/Ric/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository"
% git init
% cd ~/workarea/burp
% git add remote other "/Users/Ric/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository/.git"
% git push other master
```

What have I done here? Within the `~/workarea/burp` repository I've added a new `remote` called `other` (and you can choose whatever name you want, the usage being that `origin` is the central repository where you share your work with your colleagues when that applies).

If you look in the configuration file of `~/workarea/burp` you'll see the new remote added:

```
% cat ~/workarea/burp/.git/config
…
[remote "other"]
    url = /Users/Ric/Library/Application Support/GIT Repository/.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/other/*
```

I hope this time around I'll have done a better job at explaining all that to you ☺

HTH

Comment: Where is the var 'lib_repo' stored?  I can refer to it in future sessions.

Comment: The 'variable' lib_repo is called a remote and is defined by the command `git remote add` you could use the word poney instead, if you want!

Comment: And beware, `git remote add` and `git add` arr two different commands.

Comment: I'm aware of the 'add' difference; and I use 'remote' with remote URL repositories (e.g., github).  And I figured out the 'remote' variable.  But I still can't get a handle on create a localized remote.  I'm still getting the error 'outside repository' as mentioned above.

Comment: so I've updated my answer to explain you better how to use a remote. A **remote** is not relative to your computer and limited to services like github/gitlab/bitbucket/…. It's relative to the git repository within your computer, and point to any other git repository whether it's on a remote computer as much as within your computer in another folder. So in the end, there's no such thing as a "localized remote"!

Comment: I understand 'remote', hence attempted to have a localized 'remote', being an autonomous repository (as I've done with SVN via Cornerstone™).  My problem is having the correct syntax.  For example, how to create <name>.git repository.  I thought git init () is all thats needed.   But I get the above error.   I'll play with it again... it'll be useful for me in the future.

Comment: If you want a repository `foo.git` on your filesystem, within which you cannot browse the files, you can do `git init --bare foo.git`, and then use the path to that directory as remote. That `foo.git` repository is equivalent to the `.git` you can find in a non-bare repository.